# Polynomial map $K[t] \to K[t]$ induces flat module structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $K$ be a field and $\phi: K[t] \to K[t], t \mapsto t^n$, $n \ge 2$. This $\phi$ makes the second $K[t]$ to a $K[t]$-module by $a,b \in K[t]: a \cdot b:=\phi(a)b$.

Why this $K[t]$-module structure on $K[t]$ is *flat*?

If yes, why? And how far this example can be generalized under preservation of flatness? That is, for example is the $R[t]$-module $R[t]$ with same $\phi$ as above flat, it we now consider an arbitrary ring $R$ instead a field $K$ as above.

Other generalization is if we consider a polynomial map $\psi: K[t_1,...t_n] \to K[z_1,...,z_m]$. Is there any criterion when $\psi$ induces a *flat* $K[t_1,...t_n]$-module structure on $K[z_1,...,z_m]$?

Comment: Flat = Torsion-free for $K[t]$.

Comment: Yes, I see. But this holds as I know only for principal ideal domains (PID), like $K[t]$? So the two attempts I sketched above to generalize it in general fail?

Comment: The single variable part of your question can be read as follows: is $R[t^n]\subset R[t]$ a flat extension? The answer is positive since it is free.

Comment: @user26857: ...with canonical basis $1, t^1,..., t^n$, right? And if we consider instead of $\phi$ another map  $R[t] \to R[t]$ mapping $t $ to a non zero polynomial $f \in R[X]$. And want to decide by same logic when $R[X]$ is a flat $K[f]$-module. Does there exist a some nice crierion maybe similar to that one you gave here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3664356/quotient-of-polynomial-ring-flat-r-algebra/3667137#3667137