# When is $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ a flat morphism

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Let $K$ be a field and $\varphi: K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ a polynomial ring morphism. Assume $n, m \ge 2$. By definition $\varphi$ endows $K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ with a $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module structure.

Are there some available criterions to decide when the $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module $K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ induced in this way by $\varphi$ a *flat* $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$-module?

I want also to note that this generalizes this question: [Polynomial map $K[t] \to K[t]$ induces flat module structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3667095/polynomial-map-kt-to-kt-induces-flat-module-structure)

as far as we consider the case with more then one undeterminants. The case $n=m=1$ had always a positive answer since $K[X]$ is a PID and in this setting flat = torsion-free. For $n \ge 2$ $K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n]$ is not a PID, so the criterion is not appliable.

Another approach is to use a lemma that states that if $R \to R', S \to S'$ are flat modules, then $R \otimes S \to R' \otimes S'$ is a flat $R \otimes S$-module. The point is that I think that not every polynomial map $\varphi: K[X_1,X_2,...,X_n] \to K[Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_m]$ arises from such atomar pieces $\varphi_i: K[X_i] \to K[Y_i]$. Therefore, this approach also fails.

Comment: One obvious generalization of the $n=m=1$ case is when $n=m$ and  $K[Y]$ is a finite module over $K[X]$, where $X,Y$ stand for multivariables.

Comment: Which argument do you use here? If $X,Y$ are multivariables in more then one undeterminants then $K[X]=K[Y]$ is no more a PID, so the argument from linked question not work. Which argument do you use here?

Comment: Once $K[Y]$ is a finite module, use the fact that it is Cohen-Macaulay and use Auslander-Buchsbaum formula, to show $K[Y]$ is a projective (hence actually free) module ove $K[X]$ and in particular flat.

Comment: Why do you assume that $K[Y]$ is always a finite $K[X]$-module in case $X=Y$ (as multivariables)? Doesn't it dpend concretly on morphism $\varphi: K[X] \to K[Y]$? Assume for example $\varphi: K[X,Y,Z] \to K[X,Y,Z], X \mapsto X, Y \mapsto X, Z \mapsto X$. Under this map $K[X,Y,Z]$ is not finite $K[X,Y,Z]$-module.

Comment: The finiteness is an assumption and not a fact. I am not making any statement in general, only the case when $n=m$ AND $K[Y]$ is a finite module over $K[X]$.